# How can I add custom string preprocessing in JOOQ to sanitize strings?

Tags: jooq

I want to fix the errors, which sometimes happened in my app:

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

I think right way to solve it is to sanitize all text fields before insertion to database with

```kotlin
this.replace("\\u0000", "")
```

The question is how to implement the converter or custom binding in one place to force JOOQ invoke this `replace` function?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using jOOQ's `Converter` or `Binding`

I'm assuming this is about JSON and PostgreSQL? See also: [org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: unsupported Unicode escape sequence \u0000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72969544/521799)

It seems that a `Converter<JSON, JSON>` (or `JSONB`, respectively) would suffice?

```java
Converter.ofNullable(JSON.class, JSON.class,
    j -> j,
    j -> JSON.json(j.data().replace("\\u0000", ""))
);
```

And then, attach that everywhere using a [`forcedType`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-inline-converter/):

```xml
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.17.0.xsd">
  <generator>
    <database>
      <forcedTypes>
        <forcedType>
          <userType>org.jooq.JSON</userType>
          <converter>Converter.ofNullable(JSON.class, JSON.class,
            j -> j,
            j -> JSON.json(j.data().replace("\\u0000", ""))
          )</converter>
          <includeTypes>(?i:json)</includeTypes>
        </forcedType>
      </forcedTypes>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

#### Using JDBC

You could, of course, also just proxy JDBC and patch `PreparedStatement::setString`:

```java
@Override
public void setString(int parameterIndex, String x) throws SQLException {
    if (x == null)
        delegate.setString(parameterIndex, x);
    else
        delegate.setString(parameterIndex, x.replace("\\u0000", "");
}

// Also all the other methods that might accept strings
```

A simple way to approach this is by using jOOQ's own JDBC proxy utility types, to avoid implementing the entire JDBC API:

- [`org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultConnection.html)
- [`org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultPreparedStatement.html)

This will handle things on a lower level, including when you don't use jOOQ. However, if you're using [inline values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/), then those won't be converted by this approach, as those values are transparent to JDBC

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lukas, but no. It's about all string inputs I guess. We already have converter for all JSON/JSONB fields, but issue still appear

Comment: I'm trying to find the way to customize `DefaultStringBinding`

Comment: @RinatSuleimanov: That wasn't clear from your question. But in any case, why is it different? It's the exact same approach. There isn't some way to customise any internal binding other than supplying your own `Converter` or `Binding`

Comment: Can you please explain how for force JOOQ use the `CustomPreparedStatement` if I extend extend it from `DefaultPreparedStatement`?

Comment: You proxy your JDBC `Connection` by returning your `CustomConnection`, which in turn returns a `CustomPreparedStatement`. I.e. "proxy JDBC," it's not really jOOQ specific. jOOQ won't know you did this. Look at jOOQ's own internal `DefaultConnection` subtypes for examples how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So what I've did to solve the problem:

Added custom binding:

```kotlin
class PostgresStringsBinding : Binding<String, String> {

    override fun converter(): Converter<String, String> {
        return object : Converter<String, String> {
            override fun from(dbString: String?): String? {
                return dbString
            }

            override fun to(string: String?): String? {
                return string?.withEscapedNullChars()
            }

            override fun fromType(): Class<String> {
                return String::class.java
            }

            override fun toType(): Class<String> {
                return String::class.java
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun sql(ctx: BindingSQLContext<String>) {
        if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) ctx.render()
            .visit(DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::text") else ctx.render().sql("?::text")
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun register(ctx: BindingRegisterContext<String>) {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR)
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetStatementContext<String>) {
        ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter()).value(), null))
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetResultSetContext<String>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetStatementContext<String>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetSQLOutputContext<String>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetSQLInputContext<String>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }
}
```

and registered it as ForcedType:

```kotlin
                ForcedType()
                    .withUserType("java.lang.String")
                    .withBinding("org.example.jooqbindings.PostgresStringsBinding")
                    .withIncludeExpression(".*")
                    .withIncludeTypes("VARCHAR|TEXT")
```

Comment: @LukasEder: can you please confirm if it's a right approach?

Comment: I wouldn't implement a `Binding` when a `Converter` is sufficient, but sure, it would work just the same...