# How to add global custom converter in JOOQ

Tags: jooq

I'm actually, trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783163/how-can-i-add-custom-string-preprocessing-in-jooq-to-sanitize-strings/73785685#73785685), but have no idea how to wire up code generation configuration and DSL config.

In my project jooq is configured with `org.jooq.Configuration`, when configuration in solution uses `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration`. How to connect one to another and be sure that custom converter invoked on each insert/update query?

Answer (score 0):

Converters are attached to generated code using [forced types](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/), for example, as shown in the manual:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <forcedTypes>
        <forcedType>

          <!-- Specify the Java type of your custom type. 
               This corresponds to the Converter's <U> type. -->
          <userType>java.time.Year</userType>

          <!-- Associate that custom type with your converter. -->
          <converter>com.example.IntegerToYearConverter</converter>

          <!-- A Java regex matching fully-qualified columns. 
               Use the pipe to separate several expressions. -->
          <includeExpression>.*\.YEAR.*</includeExpression>
        </forcedType>
      </forcedTypes>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

That way, your column will always use your converter, you'll never forget it. I'm assuming you use code generation. [If not, I really recommend it](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)!